# Gradle Multi String Value files

Tags: android, intellij-idea

from this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) i had use multi language support in my Android Project, Yesterday i decided to switch to `Intellij Idea` `gradle`, when i remove value files in different language, app run normally with default language
but with multi string value file get this error

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':...:processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
/home/.../sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I
/home/.../sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar -M
/home/.../.../build/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S 
/home/.../.../build/res/all/debug -A
/home/.../.../build/assets/debug -m -J /home/.../.../build/source/r/debug -F 
/home/.../.../build/libs/...-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package ... --output-text-symbols /home/.../build/symbols/debug
Error Code:
1
Output:
/home/.../build/res/all/debug/values-Ar/values.xml: error: Duplicate file.
/home/.../build/res/all/debug/values/values.xml: Original is here.
```

Comment: instead of - try using an _ for the filename

Comment: thanks this remove error but resource value always is default and not change

Comment: the language file opened by the device is always the file with the device locale, or if not present the default one. are you using a device with the correct locale?

Comment: comments I posted are confusing, posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be with naming conventions. 
The main problem with the structure you're using is that you used a capital letter.
In android file structure in res folder should always be in lowercase.

instead of

```
values-Ar
```

you should use

```
values-ar
```

for your values folder if you want an arabic locale to find your strings,values ...

Comment: also the API guides are almost always clearer on exact context than the training guides: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html